# How to avoid the "application did not respond" when the task lasts more than 3s

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I tried to use `interaction.response.defer()` to avoid the "application did not respond" error in my program that sends a message to all channels of a category when it takes more than 3s on discord, it work but it returns the error on discord instead of "working". does anyone have a solution? Thanks in advance for your help

here is my bot:

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents().all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is up and ready! ")
    try:
        synced = await bot.tree.sync()
        print(f"Synced {len(synced)} command(s)")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


@bot.tree.command(name="sendall", description="Send a message to all the channels in a category")
@app_commands.describe(category_name="Name of the category where you want to send the message.",
                       msg="The message you want to send")
async def sendall(interaction: discord.Interaction, category_name: str, *, msg: str):
    # Récupère la catégorie correspondante
    category = None
    for c in interaction.guild.categories:
        if c.name.lower() == category_name.lower():
            category = c
            break

    # Vérifie si la catégorie est valide
    if category is None:
        await interaction.response.send_message("La catégorie spécifiée n'existe pas.")
        return

    # Envoie le message dans tous les salons de la catégorie
    for channel in category.text_channels:
        await channel.send(msg)
    await interaction.response.defer(ephemeral=True)  # defer before 3 seconds
    await asyncio.sleep(15)
    await interaction.followup.send("working")  # any follow up message you want to send



bot.run("*****")
```

I was expecting to get the "working" message from my bot after it sent the message to all the channels in a category, I tried with a smaller category that took less than 3s to send everything and it works but when I try with a category with more channels that takes more than 3s it works but it returns me the "application did not respond" error

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the `interaction.response.defer` *above* the bits of code that are going to take lots of time. Place it above the looping over the channels (or even at the very top of the interaction) and I'm pretty sure that will resolve your issue.

ie:

```py
@bot.tree.command(name="sendall", description="Send a message to all the channels in a category")
@app_commands.describe(category_name="Name of the category where you want to send the message.",
                       msg="The message you want to send")
async def sendall(interaction: discord.Interaction, category_name: str, *, msg: str):
    await interaction.response.defer(ephemeral=True)  # defer
    # Récupère la catégorie correspondante
    category = None
    for c in interaction.guild.categories:
        if c.name.lower() == category_name.lower():
            category = c
            break

    # Vérifie si la catégorie est valide
    if category is None:
        # this needs to use followup now as we deffered earlier
        await interaction.followup.send("La catégorie spécifiée n'existe pas.")
        return

    # Envoie le message dans tous les salons de la catégorie
    for channel in category.text_channels:
        await channel.send(msg)
    await asyncio.sleep(15)
    await interaction.followup.send("working")
```

Comment: Hello, just a quick question. defer() can be used on Interaction as well as Context. Should i apply defer on each command of my bot?