# How do I Post an Image With a Discord Bot in Hikari Lightbulb?

Tags: python, discord

So I am trying to make a bot that randomly generates an image with AI and posts it to my discord. The file is being saved locally and then I am trying to post it to discord with a SlashCommand. The image is generated and saved correctly. The program seems to break on the last line. I am getting the error `hikari.errors.NotFoundError: Not Found 404: (10062)` and discord is giving me `{"message": "405: Method Not Allowed", "code": 0}`.

```py
#random input just generates a string from a list
@bot.command
@lightbulb.command('hampter','Generates Hampter Image with AI')
@lightbulb.implements(lightbulb.SlashCommand)
async def generate_image(ctx):
    response = openai.Image.create(
        prompt= randomInput() ,
        n=1,
        size="512x512"
    )
    image_url = response['data'][0]['url']
    
    img_data = requests.get(image_url).content
    with open('temp.png', 'wb') as handler:
        handler.write(img_data)
    
    image = hikari.File(r'C:\filepath\temp.png')

    await ctx.respond(image)
```

I checked the docs for ctx.respond() and it says the default value for the delete_after parameter is None so I don't think ctx.respond() is timing out on my end but perhaps something on discord's end is assuming it fails and sending an error before it finishes.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide the full traceback for the error? That is typically more helpful than just a snippet of it.

Comment: @ESloman It turns out my hunch was right discord needs a response in 4 seconds-ish and the AI was taking too long.

Comment: ah okay. Well you can use `defer` to defer a response with interactions. This would give you more time to respond and generate your image and you won't get errors. I don't use hikari though and can't work out for the life of me how to do with that library so I'm not sure I can write an answer.

Comment: See this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75122577/how-to-avoid-the-application-did-not-respond-when-the-task-lasts-more-than-3s/75123426#75123426) on deferrals.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was too slow due to the openAI.generate(). Discord wants a response within 4 seconds or so. If I just shared a static image from memory using my previous method it worked fine. I can improve this but it does work with the changes I have made below:

```
@bot.command
@lightbulb.command('hampter','Generates Hampter Image with AI',auto_defer=True)
@lightbulb.implements(lightbulb.SlashCommand)
async def generate_image(ctx):
 
    response = await openai_async.generate_img(
     "APIKEYHERE",
     timeout=8,
     payload={
         "prompt": randomInput(),
         "n": 1,
         "size": "512x512"
        },
    )
    image_url = response.json()["data"][0]["url"]

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(image_url) as resp:
            if resp.status == 200:
                f = await aiofiles.open('file.png', mode='wb')
                await f.write(await resp.read())
                await f.close()


    image = hikari.File(r'C:\filepath\file.png')
    await ctx.respond(image)
```